# How to write a program, which uses 30% of CPU?

Tags: operating-system, cpu-usage

This is an interview question: write a program, which uses 30% CPU? How would you write such a program?

Comment: With a chisel, on the interviewer's forehead.

Comment: Was this concerning systems programming in C, or was it a query about using Assembly? What was the 'domain' of the question?

Comment: Yeah lets gonna test this on a 64-core processor overclock'd to 10000 THz.

Comment: I doubt on voting to have this question closed or the interviewer fired

Comment: @itsols I guess it was a C programming question

Comment: Duplicate: Special case of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551494/write-code-to-make-cpu-usage-display-a-sine-wave

Answer (score 3):

maybe this is not what you expected, but try:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define IMAX 999999
#define SLEEP 9999

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    long i;
    for(;;) {
        for(i=0; i<IMAX; i++) {}
        usleep(SLEEP);
    }
}
```

experiment with the SLEEP length. This one gave 25% load on my notebook. IMAX 999 gave 76%.
without sleep = 100%.

Comment: Now you just need to read the cpu utilization, and dynamically adjust the numbers until you achieve 30%

Answer (score 1):

This works on my laptop

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, _
                        e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    Dim numProc As Integer = Environment.ProcessorCount
    For x As Integer = 1 To numProc
        Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf foo)
        t.IsBackground = True
        t.Start()
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub foo()
    Const usage As Double = 0.35 '35%
    Dim sleep As Integer = CInt((1 - usage) * 100)
    Dim stpw As New Stopwatch
    Do
        stpw.Reset()
        stpw.Start()
        Do

        Loop While stpw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 100 - sleep
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleep)
    Loop
End Sub
```

I do wonder, as others have, about the intent of the question.